# Converting a list of files to json map

Tags: json, dictionary, jq, pathname

I've been sturggling to figure out how to use `jq` to map a list of files to a given JSON structure.  I have the following list of files:

```
/tmp/jboss/ejb-jar_3_2.xsd
/tmp/jboss/example.crt
/tmp/jboss/example.key
/tmp/jboss/incomingrunasidentityloginmodule.zip
/tmp/jboss/jboss-eap-7.0.0.zip
/tmp/jboss/jboss-eap-7.0.8-patch.zip
/tmp/jboss/keystore.jks
/tmp/jboss/logger-api.sh
/tmp/jboss/mgmt-api-example.txt
/tmp/jboss/wildfly-dist-10.1.0.Final.zip
/tmp/jboss/wildfly-dist-7.1.0.GA-redhat-8.jar
```

that I would like to convert to the following JSON structure, where the dirname is the final path in the directory structure.

```
[ 
  { dirname: "jboss", filename: "/tmp/jboss/ejb-jar_3_2.xsd" },
  { dirname: "jboss", filename: "/tmp/jboss/example.crt" },
...
...
]
```

I figure the regex I can use to extract the path is fairly simple: `.*/(.*)/` or something close to that.  However, I can't figure out how to structure the `jq` filter.  I figure it needs to be something like:

```
cat /tmp/files.txt | jq --raw-input '. |  { dirname: .match(regex).capture[0], filename: .}'
```

is as close as I've gotten, but that has several issues.  1) I can''t figure out how to use a regex for the dirname, and 2) this doesn't actually build the list of objects - it just generates multiple objects.

Is there an easy `jq` filter that I can use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jq -nR '
  [inputs | capture(".*/(?<dirname>[^/]*)/[^/]+$") + { filname: .}]'
```

Comment: Wow.  Thanks! Although I must admit I'm not entirely sure I understand how the capture is working.  Does `jq` automatically add the group to the object because it is a named group?

Comment: `capture` just produces an object.